# How to prepare cinnamon tea without sludge?

Tags: cinnamon

When I prepare my cinnamon tea in hot water it produced a sludge at the bottom but I don't drink the sludge. Is there a way to make this tea so that there is no cinnamon remaining in the cup?

Comment: Welcome, Judith! We can address your question about preventing the sludge but we do not address health benefits here, so telling you whether not drinking the cinnamon left in your cup after drinking the liquid has weight loss benefits or not isn't within our scope.. Could you please add some detail to your question to explain how you prepare your cinnamon tea?